# storing a char in a char[] makes integer from pointer without a cast?

Tags: c, arrays, type-conversion

So I am coding the skeleton for a larger program that will eventually be a message or IRC server.

The problem I am coming across is when trying to remove the end of line character from the input typed into to a character buffer by changing the value of '\n' to '\0'

The structure where the buffer is stored looks like this:

```
typedef struct{
    pthread_t tid; //the id of the thread
    char input[8192]; //message space of 2 to the 13th power
}thread_in;

thread_in user[3];
```

I then I made a temporary array pointer to my structure to make calling it easier.

```
char user_input[8192];
strncpy(user[num].input, user_input, 8192);
```

the problem is on the next line of code that give me the following warning:

> Warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

This is the code:

```
user_input[strlen(user[num].input)-1] ="\0";
```

can someone point out why it thinks the assignment is to an integer since it is a array of characters.

Comment: I should have searched for duplicates before I answered.  Searching for the quoted error message and `"\0"` found it pretty quickly.

Answer (score 1):

You want `'\0'`, not `"\0"`.  The former is a single character, the second is a string literal.  It's the conversion of `"\0"` to your `char` that is the problem; the string literal decays to a pointer and `char` is an integer type.

Answer (score 1):

`"\0"` is an array of characters and decays into a pointer.  `'\0'` is a character.  So in

```
user_input[strlen(user[num].input)-1] = "\0";
```

you're trying to store a pointer (the address of the first character of `"\0"`) in a character array.  Characters are a type of integer, so in trying to put a pointer into a character array, you have to first convert it into an character, and since characters are a type of integer, this means converting it into an integer, hence the warning:

> assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast